# non-GUI connection to local Hyper-V VM without network

Tags: virtualization, powershell, hyper-v

I have a virtual machine on Hyper-V manager (Windows 2008 R2) without a network configured on the VM. From a powershell script running on the host Windows server, I would like to query into the OS of that local VM for certain information (i.e. if a given process has finished completion).

I am using codeplex's pshyperv module (https://pshyperv.codeplex.com/) to interact with Hyper-V manager, but the only cmdlet to connect to the vm is 'New-VMConnectSession', which launches a 'vmconnect.exe' connection to the VM. Since vmconnect.exe is essentially RDP, this is not very script-friendly.

From within a host's powershell script, is there any way to send a command to a local virtual machine's OS and receive output, if no network is configured on the VM? (I believe Vmware's 'vmrun' utility has this capability)

Another way to ask this question: Does Hyper-V have a non-GUI-based form of vmconnect.exe?

(PS. Not sure if this was more stackoverflow or serverfault)

Comment: How else could you possibly connect to the machine?

Comment: Well Hyper-V manager is doing it with vmconnect... I just don't want the GUI. Remember the VM is local.

Comment: You should not think of the virtual machine as "local" in that sense; it's a *virtual **machine*** and is meant to be isolated. You can use the console or the network easily, just like any other **machine**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vmconnect` allows a client to connect to the hypervisor. It does use a RDP protocol, typically with the hypervisor acting as the "server". The VM is completely unaware of this interaction, it simply sees a VGA or similar device. On newer OSes where both Hyper-V and the VM OS support certain RDP over VMbus extension, the client is aware of the connection. But even in this case it is not processed over a "network" connection, but rather through the hypervisor.

There are no built-in ways to communicate the way you want to. You could either write a custom VMbus driver that communicates from the host to VM over Hyper-V's virtual bus; or use naped pipes mapped to serial ports; but both of these would require *some effort*.

Comment: Interesting, RDP over VMbus.. I always wondered Hyper-V was using a network protocol to interact with a VM that doesn't have network connectivity. So in Vmware, the vmrun utility has 'Guest Operating System' commands, such as 'vmrun runProgramInGuest'. I suppose I was hoping that Hyper-V has something similar implemented, but it looks lie RDP is all they used?

Comment: The Hyper-V Guest Integration Services do enable some other functions (implemented by a VMbus driver), like heartbeat and shutdown. But they don't enable any generic communication like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment says that you want to be able to run commands within a VM but you don't want the GUI.

You could enable the EMS console if the guest OS is some version of Windows Server.  This will cause a console to appear on one of the VM's serial ports.  (You choose which one.)  Then you can connect to it with PuTTY or some other VT100 emulator.  From there, you can start a command window session and run any programs you like.  (It will, of course, force you to log in.)

For more information about enabling the EMS console, see these hits:

http://www.bing.com/search?q=enable+windows+ems+console&form=TMXHSB&mkt=en-us&scope=&pq=enable+windows+ems+console&sc=0-18&sp=-1&qs=n&sk=

Of course, you could also accomplish this by upgrading your host to Server 2012 R2.  Then you can use Hyper-V to place files within the VM using PowerShell at the hosting layer.  You can set up a periodic task within the guest to run whatever it finds placed there.

Comment: SLES can still provide a serial console, this idea can be made to work, which is why I mentioned it near the very end of my answer. +1 For the Copy-VMFile info (though it requires the latest Integration Services too), didn't know about that.